# Guest user accounts cannot access sharepoint online admin centre, gets external sharing disabled error

Tags: sharepoint-online

Our 0365 Guest users added via Azure and assigned the SharePoint Administrator roles cannot access the SPoL Admin centre. They get an error messages indicating that external sharing is disabled on the SPoL Admin centre page.

How can we enable these external guest users to access the Admin centre?

Thanks

Malyka

Answer (score 1):

Adding it here in case anyone else comes across this,

Microsoft does not support external user license assignments, so it cannot share the Sharepoint Admin center with guest users.

You have 2 options:

1. Create an internal user in your tenant to access sharepoint admin portal and use  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sharepoint-admin-role to give access to the user
2. Give access to all the sites in admin to your guest as owner - this will allow management access to all the sites but will now alow admin commands like Create sites,
   Delete sites, Manage sharing settings at the organization level, Add and remove site admins or Manage site storage limits

Answer (score 0):

Sharepoint admins need to have assigned Sharepoint license so you would have to assign it to the external guest user but this is not supported.

"Global admins, SharePoint admins, and site collection admins all need to be assigned a SharePoint Online license."

REF: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sharepoint-admin-role

About subscription support for external users.

https://www.petri.com/adding-subscription-external-office-365-user

Comment: I have a guest user with a license and SharePoint Admin role assigned. He can however not access the admin center facing the same error.